# CDI - bean instances reusability

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, cdi

It seems to me that the following should result with both fields pointing the same instance,

```
class BeanToInject {
    // something
}

class TargetBean {

    @Inject
    private BeanToInject first;

    @Inject
    private BeanToInject second;

}
```

But it seems not to be true, because sysouting first and second I get

```
first: BeanToInject@2f51cd27
second: BeanToInject@1e92abdf
```

Isn't it so that beans' references should be reused across given context? 
What did I miss here?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You did not specify the scope of `BeanToInject`, and CDI's default scope is the [dependent pseudo-scope](http://docs.jboss.org/weld/reference/1.0.0/en-US/html/scopescontexts.html#d0e1816) where each injection point receives a new instance of the bean.

Answer (score 2):

You have to annotate the `BeanToInject` class as [@Singleton](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/inject/Singleton.html) to use same instance in both injection points.

Comment: I've investigated it a bit and spec says that (at)Singleton has some issues with serialization on client side. They advice using (at)ApplicationScoped instead which seems to behave like singleton.

Comment: yep, that's true for web environments in which scopes like 'Application', 'Session', 'Conversation', 'Request', 'View', etc. exist. Your question didn't specify if you we working on a web env, ejb one or just a standard application so I just came up with the simplest answer. It's ok anyway, both answers here are good enough and you are free to choose the one that you think better answers the question. :)